# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined jquery issue

Tags: jquery, wordpress, image

Can anyone tell me why this is not working?? I am trying to upload images through a Wordpress plugin but am running into some issues. The code is below. Specifically running to an error with the line in red in the below image.

The error I am getting is: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
at window.send_to_editor

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cp1D6.png)

```
window.send_to_editor = function( html ) {
       if ( sender == 'uploadlogo' ) {
           imgurl = jQuery( 'img', html ).context.match( /src="(.*?)"/ )[1];
           jQuery( '#logo' ).attr( 'src', imgurl );
           jQuery( '#team_logo' ).val( imgurl );
           jQuery( '#uploadlogo' ).hide();
           jQuery( '#placeholder-logo' ).hide();
           jQuery( '#removelogo' ).show();
           tb_remove();
       } else {
           imgurl = jQuery( 'img', html ).context.match( /src="(.*?)"/ )[1];
           jQuery( '#photo' ).attr( 'src', imgurl );
           jQuery( '#team_photo' ).val( imgurl );
           jQuery( '#uploadphoto' ).hide();
           jQuery( '#placeholder-photo' ).hide();
           jQuery( '#removephoto' ).show();
           tb_remove();
       }
   };
```

Comment: The error means that `.context` is undefined, which makes sense, [as it has been removed since jQuery 3.0](https://api.jquery.com/context/).

Comment: I see - how should I fix this?